# How to output url without domain

Tags: php, wordpress

When I'm using `wp_get_attachment_url( $name->name )` it uses the full URL (ie. `http://domain.com/files/file.zip`). It seems that this doesn't work for my use, as I only want to get the URL without the domain (just the subpath).

It works just fine if I manually enter `files/file.zip` in the code. How can I format the URL from wp_get_attachment to get the URL in this format, without the domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ltrim(parse_url('http://domain.com/files/file.zip', PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```

or

```
echo substr(parse_url('http://domain.com/files/file.zip', PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
```

Comment: Seems to work somehow to strip the URL, but it don't work for downloading. If I `echo substr(parse_url(wp_get_attachment_url( $promo->promo ), PHP_URL_PATH), 1)` I get `files/file.zip`, but the file remains corrupted if I use it in my code to set filename for download. If I manually enter `files/file.zip` in my code the file is not corrupted.

Comment: @janlindso Than the problem is in something else. Probably some script output something else. Compare both files byte by byte to see the diference.

Comment: It looks like it won't strip the URL, when I get the URL with wp_get_attachment_url. It simply returns the full URL then if I try to echo it.

Comment: @janlindso are you sure that you are getting url and not an `<a>` link there? it should strip, this is what that function `parse_url` does - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Yes, my bad. It strips, but it won't use it to download from it. If I echo your code I get `'files/file.zip'`, but the download gets corrupted if I use it after $file_url. If I copy/paste `'files/file.zip'` and add it to $file_url, the download works fine. It seems like it somehow won't "accept" it as a file path when I use your code? Even tried to add quotation marks with escape char, but it stays the same.

Comment: I can see that my question was a bit unclear originally. I edited a little bit more to fit your answer, setting it as correct, and will make a new question for my original intention. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a regex and test it like this...

```
<?php
$string = 'http://domain.com/files/file.zip';
$pattern = '/\/([\w+\/]+\.\w+)$/';
$replacement = '$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: It's supposed to be used in a WordPress plugin, so the domain must be found automatically then.

Comment: PHP is a beautiful language :P

Comment: As with Cheery's answer, this won't work either when I use the `wp_get_attachment_url( $name->name )` to get the URL, instead of writing it manually as you did.